# Split a string whenever the split character occurs exactly twice

Tags: java, regex, split

My goal is to split a string (using Java or Scala) at all occurences of "yy" that are neither followed nor preceeded by another letter "y".
Examples:

```
"aa-yy-bb" -> ["aa-", "-bb"]
"aa-yyyy-bb" -> ["aa-yyyy-bb"]
"yyy-bb" -> ["yyy-bb"]
"yy-bb" -> ["","-bb"]
"aa-yy-bb-yy" -> ["aa-","-bb-",""]
```

I ended up at `mystring.split("(^|[^y])yy([^y]|$)", -1)` but this solution is invalid since it drops any neighbored characters, e.g., it outputs `"aa-yy-bb" -> ["aa", "bb"]`.

Of course this split can be solved by parsing manually, but I wonder whether an (elegant) pattern matching solution exists. Can you find some?

Comment: Use lookarounds to ensure that you have no more `y` instances in the vicinity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lookarounds are made for that

### [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jW3iX9/1)

```
(?<!y)yy(?!y)
```

---

- `(?<!y)` Negative Lookbehind
- `yy` matches the characters yy literally (case sensitive)
- `(?!y)` Negative Lookahead

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for the [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class you could use this expression:

```
\byy\b
```

- `\b` A word boundary

Which only matches yy as a whole word. Even though lookaheads are made for these kinds of tasks a boundary matcher is shorter in this case.

EDIT: This answer doesn't work on all valid inputs.

Comment: "all occurences of "yy" that are neither followed nor preceeded by another letter "y"." So "aa-zyyx-bb" shall match, which is not true using boundary.

Comment: @DVarga You are indeed correct. I only hastily read the question but focused more on the examples. My bad.

Comment: Indeed I should have provided at least one example with characters next to "yy". But your word boundary approach is also very interesting and new to me.